# TFS (or similar alternative) for Django web app?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have enjoyed TFS (as in the new Team Foundation *Service*) for simple source control, agile project management, CI, and build in the cloud for my .NET projects.

Has anyone had success using Team Foundation Service for open source projects?  Specifically, I have a django web app currently using GitHub and [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) with tests of both the python and frontend js.  I am satisfied with these, but wish I could have bug tracking and project management built in.  Are there any comparable products that give the same suite of features in the cloud?

Comment: This question is old, I know... but, are you asking if you can post input to a TFS server via a python script (from Django), thus creating pipeline builds or whatever other functions you need out of the TFS server? If so, have you figured out a solution? I am trying to do exactly that, but I don't see any good sources on the Internet that are not written in C#.

Comment: Team Foundation Service is now called Visual Studio Code, for what it's worth.  I suspect this is much better documented now, but I haven't checked in years.  GitHub, CircleCI/Appveyor have proved great alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Well, TFS is by nature a private repository.  That's not to say that you cant configure it for openSource use but I've never seen it done.  So you wouldn't use it for OpenSource in the sense that you would make it publicly available for any and all to use.  But if you mean that you want to use it for Django Projects, PHP, Python, etc.  Nothing to it.  It works fine and works as good as you can expect from TFS.

If you want it to be open source in the true sense, then you would want to use a public repositories like GitHub.

Comment: I meant working with open source frameworks (rather than .NET), not necessarily building an open source project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could do it for you (git repository already on github, not public, 5 user limit for free account,...) but perhaps you could have a look to https://tfs.visualstudio.com/ if you like TFS...

Comment: tfs.visualstudio.com is the product I was referring to -- it is called "team foundation service".  It is perfect for me as a tool (for a few ALM features) but it doesn't have obvious python support